# Flow javascript mixed type array cannot use array functions

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I am using flow for typechecking and I have the following function.

```
function foo(x: Array<number> | Array<string>) {
  const s = x.map(i => i); 
}
```

I need to use `Array<number> | Array<string>` instead of `Array<number | string>` because of some code that is generated automatically and out of my control returns type of `Array<number> | Array<string>`.

Obviously regardless of the actual type of `x`, I *"should"* be able to perform array operations on it. However I am unable to use the `map` function on x, and am receiving the following error:

`Cannot instantiate array type because string [1] is incompatible with number [2].`

I am wondering what is the correct way to get around this and be able to perform array operations without receiving an error.

[Link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5swo44AKADwC4wBBAJyYEMBPAHm0wFsAjAKZMAfGAA+jFh04BnfE0LYA5iICUYAN6oAkLhLywssAF4w1AHS9WAB0qFTYwmoDcYVAF9UQA) to a flow fiddle.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in flow. It seems to believe that your map outputs `number | string`. It should be able to tell that elements from `x` are **always** either `number` or `string`, a choice that is made when calling the function `foo`, not within `map`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use generic in this case

```
function foo<I: number | string>(x: Array<I>) {
    const s = x.map(i => i); 
}
```

[Try it](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5swo44AeASQC4xtMBbAIwFMAnMAHzAGd8HQtgDmAPgAUAD3oBBDhwCGATxpiAlGADeqAJC4SA-mAC8YKQDomigA4TCpsWELqA3GFQBfVEA)